# Can't do ToString of any object in "release" configuration

Tags: .net, exception, uwp, win-universal-app, tostring

I'm developing UWP application, with Visual Studio 2015, and I have different behavior between "debug" and "release" configuration when, in catch, i'm try do "ToString( )" on exception object "ex".

My code do this:

```
    try
    {
        var resp2 = await new Offices().GetOfficesInCurrentLocation();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
```

In build tab, in both debug and release configuration the "optimization code" option is unchecked.

- Debug: I can "ToString( )" of exception to see stack & message
  [image]
- Release: I can watch "ex" object, and $exception, but I can't "ToString( )" the exception. The exception says "Internal error evaluating System.Object.ToString( ) method".
  [image]

Why? Some kind of configuration?

**EDIT:**

If i put in "cath" something like

```
string log = ex.ToString();
```

Works fine, and I **CAN** read "ex", so is only in "inspector" tab where i can't execute "ToString" over "ex" object.

**EDIT 2:**
The problem has no relatioship with "catch" or "exception". I have tried this
var X = Datetime.Now;
and give me the same problem in "inspector" tab when i'm try ToString "X" object
[image]

Comment: That is a screendump from the debugger, right? Try writing it to a logfile.

Comment: You are rigth, this is screenshot of debugger. When i'm try to do something like this "string log = ex.ToString();" i can read it, so... why in debugger i can't do the ToString() only in release configuration?

Comment: *Expression evaluation* is likely one of the toughest problems to tackle in a debugger. I'm actually surprised, how often it works. In your situation it's probably best to set up your debugger to break, when an exception is **thrown**, as opposed to when it's caught. That'll usually produce a lot more helpful information, than calling `ToString()` on the exception object you caught.

Comment: The Debug configuration disables optimization. In Release you are trying to look at something (the variable `ex`) already optimized out of existence.